# Podemos ter avisos especiais nas perguntas polêmicas?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto

Estava passeando pelo Programmers.SE e notei algo que eu não tinha visto antes. Veja a pergunta https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103659/how-can-one-manage-thousands-of-if-then-else-rules.

Lá tem um aviso de como a pergunta deve ser respondida:

[image: Aviso]

Este aviso é colocado de forma automática por algum critério que dispara o gatilho? É colocado por moderadores (parece que pode quando a pergunta é protegida https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/103659/revisions)? Pelo próprio OP?

Ele é personalizável para cada situação?

Existe a possibilidade de termos aqui no SOpt algo semelhante?

Acredito que alguns alertas assim podem tornar algumas perguntas mais palatáveis para alguns usuários. Evitaria a colocação de apenas *links*, respostas sem utilidade real. Quem sabe até poderia transformar listas de compras em recomendações plausíveis, debates sem sentido em troca de informações proveitosas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse aviso pode ser colocado por moderadores, independentemente de a pergunta ser protegida ou não. Ainda não usei esse recurso, mas pela interface acredito que o aviso não é editável. O diálogo de inserção disso também inclui outros dois avisos, um pedindo citações e fontes, e outro indicando que o post diz respeito a um evento pontual (talvez sirva em *[Erro ao retornar endereço do CLGeocorder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16857/erro-ao-retornar-endereco-do-clgeocorder)*).

O aviso que você mencionou parece ser útil para perguntas que recebem muitas respostas curtas e ruins – portanto perguntas que possivelmente já tenham sido protegidas no passado para tentar coibir isso.

Se você acredita que uma pergunta mereça esse aviso, sinalize, e idealmente coloque o assunto em discussão no meta. Como o site ainda é muito novo, tenho dúvidas se alguma pergunta já "sofreu" o suficiente para merecer o aviso.