# Podemos ter avisos especiais nas perguntas/respostas polêmicas?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Fiz uma [pergunta com quase exato mesmo título](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1447/101), mas com propósito diferente. Agora quero saber se nós moderadores podemos aplicar esse aviso e quais os critérios para isto.

Existem muitas perguntas que podem estar causando mais mal do que bem quando tem uma resposta ruim, principalmente aceita. Eu acho que isto denigre a reputação do site como um todo, você pode discordar, por isso abri esse debate. Já existem avisos padrões do sistema que são usados em outros sites e aqui praticamente não são. A ideia aqui é ver o que acham sobre isso.

O aviso a ser colocado seria um destes:

[image: Motivos porque uma pergunta é ruim: citação necessária, evento atual, explicação insuficiente].

Então a primeira questão é se vocês aprovam fazer isto. Tem vantagens e desvantagens. Não é algo fácil de fazer e não pode ser trivial colocar algo assim.

A segunda questão é quais serão os critérios para determinar que algo é ruim e terá este tipo de aviso. Um dos problemas é que normalmente ele cabe justamente onde parece estar em ordem, onde tem aceitação e possivelmente com votos positivos. Afinal, se já tiver informação de que ali não tem qualidade (estar placar negativo) é menos necessário ter um aviso.

E ainda temos a questão de como proceder. Um moderador pode fazer por conta própria? Só deve fazer depois de discutir com outros moderadores? Só pode fazer provocado por uma sinalização específica dizendo do problema e que merecia um aviso? Só pode fazer com um debate no meta? Qual o processo para retirar o aviso se acharem irregular? Sugira como deveria ser o procedimento para funcionar melhor, claro, se você acha que deve ter o aviso.

Sinta-se a vontade pra falar o que quiser sobre o assunto. O debate é feito de participação e pluralidade.

Particularmente acho isso necessário em muitos casos, e podendo usar isto acho que podemos deixar algumas perguntas abertas que hoje seriam fechadas pelo potencial de problema que ela pode trazer. Claro que se deixar perguntas abertas com esse potencial tende a usar mais esse aviso e teria que ser um processo simples de aplicá-lo.

Comment: Quanto a respostas longas tenho um questionamento, vejo que no SOen a varias respostas curtas que funcionam sem nenhuma explicação com muitos votos, por que isso ocorre?

Answer (score -1):

A comunidade não deu sinais claros que quer isso, nem demonstrou não querer. Acredito que dá margem para os moderadores usaram mais as ferramentas, sem exageros. Se alguém tiver mais a dizer ainda fica aqui disponível.